# How to affect VMs in a network using WannaCry?(Cuckoo Sandbox)

Tags: virtualization, wannacry

I have a network consisting of 2 VMs(Windows 7).

VM1:- `192.168.56.101`

VM2:- `192.168.56.102`

Both are connected to vboxnet0 (`192.168.56.1`).

I infected VM1 using WannaCry ransomware but the ransomware does not spread to VM2.

I've disabled windows firewall&defender and can ping both VMs from each other and they are visible in the NETWORKS tab as well.

I though the ransomware would spread to the second VM but it does not happen

Am I missing something?

Comment: This may help https://www.securityweek.com/patched-wannacry-ransomware-has-no-kill-switch

Comment: @tungsten Thanks for the article. I guess it's not going to happen in that case.

Comment: I'm using a host only network and I guess it means that my host Linux is also a part of that network with the infected VM. Am I going to be in trouble?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have Windows 7 patched?

Comment: @RaimondsLiepiņš I'm sure about that. I used the sp1 windows7 ultimate iso file for making the vm. I checked the version and it was vulnerable to wannacry.